# Finding and executing org-babel snippets programatically

Tags: org-mode, org-babel

I currently I have a couple of org-babel shell [snippets](http://people.linaro.org/~alex.bennee/org/apm.html#sec-2-2) to package up a build and push it to a server for later usage. This also handily keeps a reference to the last execution of the snippet so I can remember what was last uploaded and when.

I was thinking I could further automate my process by hooking into `compilation-finish-functions` to look-up a babel snippet and execute it on successful compilation. What's the best way to organise the babel snippets and call the snippets programmatically? I was wondering if I can use `:tags:` or if I can just call up the snippet by `#+:NAME` by searching all my `org-agenda-files`. I was planning in storing the target babel function in the project's `.dir-locals.el`.

It would also be nice to mark a snippet as trusted whilst it was unchanged so I didn't need to confirm every execution.

Comment: Maybe I'm just tired, but I had to read the second paragraph a few times to understand what was being asked. :-) So you want to find a code block by name or tag, across all agenda files? I didn't quite get what `.dir-locals` has to do with it.

Comment: @Malabarba I seem to understand that the question is about getting something like `(invoke-babel-snippet name)` at the end of a compilation. And the `.dir-locals.el` would help define `name` in that case.

Comment: @Malabarba: what Sigma said, sorry for the confusing wording. I'll see if I can improve the language.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For the first part, the following can move to a specific named snippet and execute it

```
(defun my/invoke-babel-named (name)
  (interactive)
  (save-excursion
    (org-babel-goto-named-src-block name)
    (org-babel-execute-src-block-maybe)))
```

You can define snippets as trusted/untrusted based on varying factors, however I don't think there is any built-in mechanism to trust based on content.  The following should work based on limited testing (2 code blocks of different languages, making a few changes to ensure it re-prompted).

```
(defvar my/babel-hashes 'nil)
(defun my/babel-hashed-confirm (lang body)
  (let ((check (list lang (md5 body))))
    ;; If not hashed, prompt
    (if (not (member (list lang (md5 body)) my/babel-hashes))
        ;; Ask if you want to hash
        (if (yes-or-no-p "Store hash for block? ")
            ;; Hash is added, proceed with evaluation
            (progn
              (add-to-list 'my/babel-hashes check)
              'nil)
          ;; Return 't to prompt for evaluation
          't))))

(setq org-confirm-babel-evaluate 'my/babel-hashed-confirm)
```

`org-babel-confirm-evaluate` does not provide the code block name so the hash will be added for every change rather than stored on a per-block basis.  The downside being frequent changes will lead to a very large hash.  The upside being that reverting changes to the code block will still have the hash in memory if already accepted.